# Read and write system calls w/o buffer

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I need to read data from a file and write it to another file in C.
I am using the system calls `open`, `read` and `write`.

**I fear the buffer i am using is causing me to lose some data.
Can i somehow bypass the buffer?**

Here is the loop responsible for writing the data to the file:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[250]; 
    ssize_t ret;
    while(!timeIsUp)    
    {
        ret = read(file, &buffer[0], 256);
        if (ret > 0 && ret <= 256)
        {
           write(outpud, &buffer[0], (ssize_t) ret_fd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, the int main() isn't formatted to be part of the code block.

Comment: Erm... you want to read data, *not store it anywhere*, and then write it again? Besides, what makes you think the buffer makes you lose data? Also, code does not compile. Post real code, not pseudocode.

Comment: Note: `250 != 256` ...

Comment: The buffer should not make you lose data. To directly write you can do this in c++ but not c (which will also internally use a buffer though)

Comment: You're reading 256 bytes into a 250 char buffer. Use `sizeof buffer` to avoid magic numbers, or use a `#define`.

Comment: @Koga: Edited. Feel free to delete your comment.

Comment: Note2: `ret_fd != ret`

Comment: Also, `&buffer[0]` is just a verbose way of saying `buffer`. Don't waste tokens, you might run out.

Answer (score 1):

You write out `(ssize_t) ret_fd` bytes, while you read `ret` bytes.

Rewrite like this:

```
write(outpud, &buffer[0], ret);
```

(Not to mention this isn't a complete example you have given, many variables are undefined, and the file is never opened. Please post real code.)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 logical mistakes I found in your code (there are compilation errors too).

1. Declared buffer with size 250 and you are trying to read/write up to 256.
   It may cause segmentation fault.
2. For write, you are using size as `ret_fd` . It should be `ret`.

Comment: for first point, in more general case, it's _undefined behavior_, so it may cause segmentation fault, or not, have side visible effect or not, or anything unpredictable behavior

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work (as many have commented to the question, and some answered), and even if fixed, is likely to lose data, but not because of using a buffer.

Consider the following (untested, so report any errors you might find in a comment, so I can fix it) example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#ifndef  COPY_BUFFER_SIZE
#define  COPY_BUFFER_SIZE  262144
#endif

struct copystatus {
    off_t  bytes;
    int    error;
};

struct timeout;
extern int timeout_elapsed(struct timeout *);

int copyfd(const int tofd, const int fromfd,
           struct copystatus *toinfoptr,
           struct copystatus *frominfoptr,
           struct timeout *limit)
{
    const size_t  size = COPY_BUFFER_SIZE;
    char         *data, *p, *q;
    ssize_t       n;
    struct copystatus toinfo, frominfo;
    int           retval = 0;

    toinfo.bytes = 0;
    toinfo.error = 0;
    frominfo.bytes = 0;
    frominfo.bytes = 0;

    if (toinfoptr) *toinfoptr = toinfo;
    if (frominfoptr) *frominfoptr = frominfo;

    if (tofd == -1 || fromfd == -1)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    data = malloc(size);
    if (!data)
        return errno = ENOMEM;

    while (1) {

        if (timeout_elapsed(limit)) {
            retval = frominfo.error = ETIMEDOUT;
            break;
        }

        n = read(fromfd, data, size);
        if (n == -1) {
            /* Interrupted by a signal? Timeout? */
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            /* No, an error occurred. */
            retval = frominfo.error = errno;
            break;

        } else
        if (n == 0)
            break; /* No more input. */
        else
        if (n < -1) {
            /* Library/kernel error. Might occur if size > 2GB. */
            retval = frominfo.error = EIO;
            break;
        }

        frominfo.bytes += (off_t)n;

        p = data;
        q = data + n;
        while (p < q) {

            if (timeout_elapsed(limit)) {
                retval = toinfo.error = ETIMEDOUT;
                break;
            }

            n = write(tofd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
            if (n == -1) {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                    continue;
                retval = toinfo.error = errno;
                break;
            } else
            if (n < 1) {
                /* Should not occur. */
                retval = toinfo.error = EIO;
                break;                 
            }

            p += n;
            toinfo.bytes += (off_t)n;
        }
        if (retval)
            break;
    }

    free(buffer);

    if (toinfoptr) *toinfoptr = toinfo;
    if (frominfoptr) *frominfoptr = frominfo;

    return errno = retval;
}
```

The above code reads data from one descriptor, writing it to another, with full error checking. It returns 0 if successful, or an `errno` error code otherwise. (Note that it is not common to assign the return value to `errno`; this is just my own style, and only used then the return value is always a valid `errno` value.)

If non-NULL, the two copy status structures are filled with the number of bytes copied, and error code particular to that descriptor. In particular, if a timeout occurs, only one of their `error` fields will be set to `ETIMEDOUT`. (It is a POSIX.1 error code, "Connection timed out", not defined in C89/C99/C11.)

The function is designed to work with timeout mechanisms that use signal delivery (to an empty signal handler) to interrupt a blocking I/O call. (In such cases, the call will return `-1` with `errno == EINTR`.) It does not work with nonblocking sockets; in that case, a `select()` loop would be better, and using either `gettimeofday()` or POSIX.1 `clock_gettime()` to obtain the real-world time, to internally compute the elapsed time for the copy operation, without the need for an external timeout checker function. A mixed blocking/nonblocking operation in a single function is possible, but awfully messy, hard to maintain and understand, and therefore strongly recommended against. (One can use `fcntl(descriptor,F_GETFL) & O_NONBLOCK` to find out whether a descriptor is set to nonblocking or not.)

When `fromfd` refers to a file on a local filesystem, all reads will return either the requested size, -1 for errors, or a short count or zero at the end of the file. When `tofd` refers to a file on a local filesystem, all writes will write and return the amount requested, unless an error occurs, in which case they will return -1. This does *not* mean one should feel free to assume this is commonly the case; in fact, **local file behaviour is the exception**.

In Linux, and all POSIXy systems, character devices and pseudoterminals can be treated as files without any special handling from the application. However, it is *common* for those to return short reads, and occasionally even short writes.

Furthermore, although `recv*()` and `send*()` families of functions are normally used with socket descriptors, one can just as easily use `read()` and `write()`. It is very common for reads from and writes to sockets to return short counts, and occasionally even errors (for example, network outages), although really long blocking is more common (due to e.g. long default TCP timeout).

This is why the above example code does not assume reads and writes behave in any specific way. It is not optimal in that it always interleaves reads and writes, and assumes blocking descriptors. If you need such a function in real life, you might be copying several files -- either in parallel, or sequentially --, and using a `select()`-based nonblocking approach that copies multiple files at the same time, would probably be preferable *to the users of the application*, especially when the target files reside on different mount points. (Parallel approach tends to be faster if each target file resides on a different mount point, or is a char device or socket; sequential approach is faster if the targets are files and on the same mount point.)

Answer (score 0):

High school question but here:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[2] = {'\0'};
    int readfd;
    int writefd;

    readfd = open("myfile", O_RDONLY);
    writefd = open("myfile1", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);

    while (read(readfd, &buf, 1) != 0)
    {
            write(writefd, buf, 1);
    }

    close(writefd);
    close(readfd);
    return (0);
}
```

readfd is the file you want to read from.
writefd is the file you want to write to.

no error testing or cleanup.